# unable to get height and width of html element for firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
getheightWidth(obj, className)
{
 var o = new Object();
 var span = document.createElement("P");
 document.body.appendChild(span);
 span.className = className;
 span.style.visibility = "hidden";
 o.width = $(span).width();
 o.height = $(span).height();
 return o;
}
```

I am unable to get height and width of element. According to specified in class.

Comment: class having following properties 
{
 width: 350px;
 height:100px;
}

Comment: o.width is use for set property of o variable.

Comment: firefox $(span).width() returning 0 (zero) but it should return 350 
and it is working fine for crome IE

Comment: nobody know abut it. :)

Comment: You can not get an element's height/width before it is being appended to dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

### SAMPLE HTML

```
<div class="test1">dd</div>
```

### JS

```
 function getheightWidth(className)
{
 var o = new Object();
 var span = document.createElement("P");
 span.className = className;
 span.style.visibility = "hidden";
 $("div.test1").append(span);   // append into html
 o.width = $(span).width();
 o.height = $(span).outerHeight(false);
 return o;
}
var obj=getheightWidth("test")

console.log(obj);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/58a9P/1/)

NOTE: You can not get an element's height/width before it is being appended to dom

Comment: @Vinay Sharma now check it

Comment: i have modified my code as you suggest me now it working fine for other browsers but not for Firefox

Comment: @Bala + vinaySharma: You should specify the version of firefox that you are using..

Comment: i am using Firefox 30.0

Comment: @VinaySharma It is working fine in v29.0, and i'll let you know what happens in v30. Currently updating it..

Comment: by adding breakpoint on o.width $(span).width() it is showing 0

Comment: @VinaySharma It is working fine in V32. You must be having error somewhere else in your code/

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter is obj and returning o that's typo:

```
getheightWidth(o, className) //replaced obj to o
{
 var span = document.createElement("P");
 span.className = className;
 span.style.visibility = "hidden";
 o.width = $(span).width();
 o.height = $(span).outerHeight(false);
 return o;
}
```

Comment: dear sir in firefox $(span).width() returning 0 (zero) but it should return 350

Comment: do you have solution for it

Comment: I was just busy, please tell me what the problem you have?

Comment: you wanted to get the width of span which is inline by default and so can't get width, you need to explicitly apply the display: inline-block or block to that span and only it would get the width....

Comment: span.style.width="350px"

Comment: but can you please suggest me why these properties not getting apply by class. and how we can test that it is having these properties

Comment: I already said that span is inline by default so it would not get width and height....

Comment: but it is not a span, it is a paragraph. var span = document.createElement("P"); , i am creating paragraph type of element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58476/discussion-between-vinay-sharma-and-c-link-nepal).

Answer (score 0):

problem was related to window. here i was creating element span in current window and try to get on upper window that's why i was enable to get values of variable o.

```
getheightWidth(obj, className)
{
 var o = new Object();
 var span = document.createElement("P");
 window.top.document.body.appendChild(span);
 span.className = className;
 span.style.visibility = "hidden";
 o.width = $(span).width();
 o.height = $(span).height();
 return o;
}
```